# Unit conversions return error message "could not find function "m_to_ft."

Tags: r, function, unit-conversion

The "measurements" package should be installed and loaded. My first unit conversion (copied below) worked just fine:

```
temp_f <- 100
temp_c <- F_to_C(temp_f) 
print(paste(temp_f, "ºF is equivalent to", temp_c, "ºC"))
```

However, the following conversion will not run:

```
dist_meters <- 100  
dist_feet <- m_to_ft(dist_meters)
```

I keep getting the error message:

> "Error in m_to_ft(dist_m) : could not find function "m_to_ft""

As far as I can tell I'm writing the code correctly and the package seems to be installed and loaded correctly since it worked on the first conversion.

I have tried changing the capitalization (I had to do this with the first conversion before it ran correctly).

Comment: `F_to_C()` nor `m_to_ft()`are part of measurements package, `F_to_C()`must origin from some other library or perhaps from a script you are working with. `measurements` syntax looks like  `measurements::conv_unit(100, "m", "ft")`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think measurements package has `m_to_ft()`, you can use `conv_unit()` which converts common units of measurements:

```
dist_m <- 100
dist_ft <- conv_unit(dist_m, "m", "ft")
print(paste(dist_m, "meters is equivalent to", dist_ft, "feet"))
```

output:

```
[1] "100 meters is equivalent to 328.083989501312 feet"
```